# Get mean of previous 6 hours in R

Tags: r

I have a dataset with a level of radiation per hour. I need to get the average level of radiation from the previous 6 hours. So for point c I need: mean(data$radiation[(c-7):(c-1)])

This would be a solution to my problem, if the dataset where to be complete (it is not, sometimes a few hours are missing) and I have no idea how to automate it without a for-loop (which I would like to avoid as there are 199056 entries)

I have the data in a data frame with radiation and time in a POSIXct format:

```
            GLOBAL_radiation             POSTIME
    1383116               98 2016-06-10 18:00:00
    1383118               55 2016-06-10 19:00:00
    1383125               26 2016-06-10 20:00:00
    1383130                6 2016-06-10 21:00:00
    1383137                0 2016-06-10 22:00:00
    1383142                0 2016-06-10 23:00:00
```

I've been cracking my brain on this for a while now, I do hope a function exists for this that I'm unaware of. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to CV. We are dealing mainly with statistical questions here rather than computational ones. If you are asking for methods for dealing with missing values, this would be on topic. If you are solely asking for a function in R to achieve your computation, then this would not be.

Comment: The `rollapply` function in the `zoo` package may be helpful. Or the `rollmean` function.

Comment: @Sjoerd - the "apply" can be quite fast (for R).  R is not known for much resembling speed - that is not its value proposition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not quite sure if this meet your needs, but I give it a try:

```
library(dplyr)

# define start value for date, which is assumed to be the 
# last value in the time-vector
start <- dat$POSTIME[nrow(dat)]

# compute difference of all time points in relation
# to latest time point in data set
dat$hours <- as.vector(difftime(start, dat$POSTIME, units = "hours"))

# create a "grouping" vector, where all 6-hours-span-timepoints
# are grouped together
dat$grp <- as.integer(dat$hours / 6)

# group by 6-hours-span and compute mean for each
# 6-hours time-period
dat %>% group_by(grp) %>% summarise(mean(STRALING))
```